# debian, second monitors fail,

Tags: linux, debian, multiple-monitors

i have a problem that i can't solve for a couple of days.
Previously i had an ubuntu (14, 16) but a program that was very important for me(SW4STM32, based on eclipse) didn't work properly. And eclipse at all was veeeery slow, despite of the fact that i have powerful computer(laptop).
Recently I installed Debian 8, and program works fine now(much more better than on ubuntu), however I've got another problem - my second monitor doesn't work(it works sometimes, in 5-10% of cases, when I turn comp. on), first I tried gnome, then KDE, however it didn't help. So, may be someone had the same problem and can give me a solution or at least tell me where the problem?

PS it should be said, that I didn't install any video drivers, on dabian manual page it was said that OS should work fine without any. 
PPS I absolutely sure that monitor is ok, because i have windows as a second OS and on windows both monitors work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for help, don't know what I would do without all of you:D
I didn't get finally how it works, but during the work I lanch arandr change resolution of black display, click ok, than chang it back, click ok and .... magic! second display starts working. May be it will help someone in the future;)

Comment: additionally I created a shell script that do it instead of me. Still don't know why it works so, but it works